# Deleting rows with certain string in list of data frames

Tags: r, string, list, delete-row

I have a list of data frames that look as follows:

```
df1<- data.frame(x1=c("Ben","ABC","Alex","Tim", "Lisa", "MJ", "ABC"), 
x2=c(3,NA,9,5,7,2,NA), 
x3=c(3,NA,6,9,3,1,NA))

df2<- data.frame(x1=c("Alex","ABC","Tyler","Ben", "Lisa", "MJ", "ABC"), 
x2=c(3,NA,2,5,7,2,NA), 
x3=c(3,NA,6,5,3,2,NA))

df3<- data.frame(x1=c("Lisa","ABC","Tyler","Ben", "Lisa", "MJ", "ABC"), 
x2=c(3,NA,9,5,7,2,NA), 
x3=c(3,NA,6,9,3,1,NA))

df_list<-list(df1, df2, df3)
```

I want to delete all rows that contain the string "ABC" in all data frames in the list. In reality, my list of data frames contains many more data frames. Therefore, I do not want to perform the operation on each data frame seperately but directly to the list of data frames.

How could I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Note that your reproducible example is not reproducible, you have 5 values for x2 and x3, while you have 7 values for x1. Also, "ABC" in any column or just x1?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the code. The rows where I have "ABC" in x1 are empty for x2 and x3. I only have "ABC" in x1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lapply` with `grepl` like this:

```r
lapply(df_list, \(x) x[!grepl("ABC", x$x1),])
#> [[1]]
#>     x1 x2 x3
#> 1  Ben  3  3
#> 3 Alex  9  6
#> 4  Tim  5  9
#> 5 Lisa  7  3
#> 6   MJ  2  1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      x1 x2 x3
#> 1  Alex  3  3
#> 3 Tyler  2  6
#> 4   Ben  5  5
#> 5  Lisa  7  3
#> 6    MJ  2  2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>      x1 x2 x3
#> 1  Lisa  3  3
#> 3 Tyler  9  6
#> 4   Ben  5  9
#> 5  Lisa  7  3
#> 6    MJ  2  1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: How can I extend this code to any form of text not just "ABC"?

Comment: Hi @ZayzayR, If you want to detect multiple string you could use for example `"ABC|MJ"` to detect ABC or MJ because of |.

Answer (score 0):

```
> lapply(df_list,function(x){x[x$x1!="ABC",]})

[[1]]
    x1 x2 x3
1  Ben  3  3
3 Alex  9  6
4  Tim  5  9
5 Lisa  7  3
6   MJ  2  1

[[2]]
     x1 x2 x3
1  Alex  3  3
3 Tyler  5  5
4   Ben  7  3
5  Lisa  2  2
6    MJ NA NA

[[3]]
     x1 x2 x3
1  Lisa  3  3
3 Tyler  9  6
4   Ben  5  9
5  Lisa  7  3
6    MJ  2  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df_list %>%  
  map(., ~ .x %>% 
        filter(x1 != "ABC"))

[[1]]
    x1 x2 x3
1  Ben  3  3
2 Alex  9  6
3  Tim  5  9
4 Lisa  7  3
5   MJ  2  1

[[2]]
     x1 x2 x3
1  Alex  3  3
2 Tyler  2  6
3   Ben  5  5
4  Lisa  7  3
5    MJ  2  2

[[3]]
     x1 x2 x3
1  Lisa  3  3
2 Tyler  9  6
3   Ben  5  9
4  Lisa  7  3
5    MJ  2  1
```